# SSO get username / domain

Tags: .net, single-sign-on

I'm trying to implement SSO (Single Sign On) but I can't get the correct username.

At my place, when I retrieve the currently logged on user I get: `USER@DOMAIN`. Which is correct. When the same code is executed at the customer, it returns: `USER@DOMAIN`. But in that situation; it is **not** correct. The expected value at the customer is `USER@INTRANET.DOMAIN`.

I'm not familiar enough with SSO to say anything about the INTRANET part. At the customer, other software uses SSO as well and therefore it is required that 'my' software formats the user/domain into `USER@INTRANET.DOMAIN`.

I've tried several pieces of code to retrieve the user/domain of the currently logged in user. The results below are from the customer.

```
UserPrincipal.Current.UserPrincipalName - returns user@domain 
System.Environment.UserDomainName - returns INTRANET
WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name - returns INTRANET\user
```

So I'm looking for a way to retrieve the complete username of the currently logged in user with the 'subdomain' (INTRANET) as well. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit: ** I rephrased my question. I feel like my English is getting worse by day... :S

Comment: How do you know the 'correct' one (USER@INTRANET.DOMAIN)?  Use that method.  If you got username and full domain name and added with a '@', do that in code - if you looked at some dialog or commandline readout, what tool?  Discover which API it uses

Comment: Good question. I'll update my question to rephrase the problem and answer your question. (Comment doesn't allow markup etc)

Comment: Do you have an active directory or other directory service in each environment? You can use that to look up additional information using the info you have at the moment. Sounds like your customer has an environment like that.

Comment: Yes, our customer uses active directory. I was also thinking about looking up info, but I need the username for that, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code.

```
string domainName = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
string nametext = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.Split('\\')[1];

//OR 
// string nametext = Environment.UserName;

string fullname = String.Format("{0}@{1}", nametext, domainName);
```

Comment: That seems to work at first sight! I'll continue with this tomorrow. Thanks for now! But how on earth did you find this IPGlobalProperties class :P

Comment: Well thank you very much! The code you provided works in our situation! I googled with the wrong keywords and unfortunately there are way to much ways to retrieve (a part of) the domain...

Comment: In this instance will domainName be the domain of the application or the domain of the user accessing the application?  The documentation says "Provides information about the network connectivity of the local computer.", what do they mean by local computer?